# What's the difference between adjectives "supplementary" and "supplemental"?

Tags: differences, adjectives

I'm writing a multiple choice test (MCQ) and I'll add a page of extra questions. I'm hesitating between naming them "*[supplementary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supplementary) list/page of questions*" and "*[supplemental](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supplemental) list/page of questions*", but I don't get the difference of meaning.

According to Wiktionary, they have distinct meaning and aren't considered synonyms:

> **supplemental** (*comparative* **more supplemental**, *superlative* **most supplemental**)
>
> 1. Acting to supplement.
> 2. Appending.
>
> **supplementary** (*comparative* **more supplementary**, *superlative* **most supplementary**)
>
> 1. Additional; added to supply what is wanted.

I could potentially use alternative formulations like *additional questions* or *extra questions*, but my concern here is to understand the difference between adjectives *supplemental* and *supplementary*.

I tried to look at some well-reviewed conventions, like from unicode.org lists, but they use both terminologies without me understanding why:

- [Supplemental Mathematical Operators](https://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_2A00.html)
- [Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs](https://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_1F900.html)
- [Supplementary Private Use Area-A](https://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_FFF80.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question! The additional test questions are "added to supply what is wanted" in this case more of them.
So it should be "This is a page of *Supplementary* questions"

*Supplemental* is used more in the sense of adding value or function or information. A further definition of a word, more functionality to a process.

*Supplementary* is adding more of the same without necessarily improving the whole.

Comment: 'Supplemental' _is_ synonymous with 'supplementary' but also has the sense 'serving to complete' [[The Content Authority](https://thecontentauthority.com/blog/supplemental-vs-supplementary-2)] (ie the words are not always interchangeable).